# How to make this LINQ statement more elagant?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Physicians to OfficeStaff is a many to many relationship. When I am adding an office staff member I want to make sure that the Sponsoring Physician's ID assigned to the entity is presently in the DB already, so I do this:

```
foreach (var sponsoringPhysician in officeStaff.Physicians)
{
    if (!container.Physician.Any(q => q.Equals(sponsoringPhysician)))
        throw new ApplicationException("A sponsoring physician is not found for staff: " + user.AccountName);
}
```

The equality check is set to check based on ID's.

How to replace the code in the foreach with a sub query?

Comment: If you want this to be a subquery, it might be helpful to see the query that this is subbing. At first glance, I would be inclined to use a Left (defaultIfEmpty) join and then in your iteration check for null on the physician to throw the exception. You can't throw inside of a subquery unless you use a First/Single rather than FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
var hasNoSponsor = officeStaff.Physicians.FirstOrDefault(p => !container.Physician.Any(q => q.Equals(p)));
if (hasNoSponsor != null) throw new ApplicationException("A sponsoring physician is not found for staff: " + user.AccountName);
```

*edit*: I think this can further be simplified as:

```
if (!container.Physician.Any(p => officeStaff.Physicians.Contains(p))) {
    throw new ApplicationException("A sponsoring physician is not found for staff: " + user.AccountName);
}
```

-Remember that `Contains` performs equality-comparing using `Equals`under the hood.

Comment: @Nizlor, your code results in this: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Domain.PhysicianPortal.Physician'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Well, is container.Physician an enumeration or not? It sounds like it isn't, but you *are* using it with an `Any()`-clause in the question, which indicates it is. Does your `posted` code compile? Edit: Which of the two examples fail? Try splitting them over multiple lines to find the exact statement which fails.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
if(officeStaff.Physicians.
         Join(container.Physician,
           po => po.ID, pc => pc.ID, 
           (po,pc)=>new {po}).
           Where(po.Equals(pc)).Any()
     ){
     throw new ApplicationException("A sponsoring physician is not found for staff: " + user.AccountName);
   }
```